# Grails many-to-one cascaded deletion trouble

Tags: grails

Given the following domain classes:

```
class Location {
    String city

    static belongsTo = [ author: Author ]
}
class Author {
    String name
    Location location
}
```

when I do this:

```
def l = new Location(city: "Boston")
l.save()

def a = new Author(name: "Niall Ferguson", location: l)
a.save()
```

I can delete my author with `a.delete()` but if I try to delete my location with `l.delete()` I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations): [Location#17]
```

ok fine so let me remove the object to be deleted object from associations and try again:

```
author.location = null // Assuming these two statements are the right way
location.author = null // to to this.
```

now when I try `l.delete()` again I get this:

```
ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKAC2D218B9615BDBA: PUBLIC.AUTHOR FOREIGN KEY(LOCATION_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.LOCATION(ID) (18)";
```

So what am I doing wrong? In this scenario is it even possible to delete the location and keep the author?

Comment: With the configuration `static belongsTo = [ author: Author ]` you get a behavior as explained in the [gorm docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne) (Example b). I assume that with explicit setting the belongsTo config, you want to say that a Location can't exists without a Author. I would suggest to remove the belongsTo association, so that a location can be removed without removing the referencing author entries.

Comment: @MarioDavid After removing the belongsTo, I still cannot delete only the location by itself, I get the second error I posted in my question, the integrity constraint violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to reproduce your code, my first error was in l.save(). In your class, the field author in your domain Location is required. You can not save a location without a author in your example. **You should always check the return value of save() or use failOnError: true** to uncover little mistakes like that.

That being said, it seems to me you are modelling a one-to-one relationship. Not a many-to-one, otherwise how can a Location have one Author? *(I agree that the grails documentation is a little confusing in this matter)*

Instead, I create the following classes, assuming that a author have a location, but the same location can be referenced by many authors.

```
class Author {
    String name
    Location location
}

class Location {
    String city
}
```

Now you are left with your Referential integrity constraint violation, basically, you can not delete a location without deleting first all the authors that are related to that location.

If you want the delete cascading to work, I would use a bidirectional one-to-many relationship like this

```
class Author {
    String name
    static belongsTo = [location: Location]
}
class Location {
    String city
    static hasMany = [authors: Author]
}
```

And about your last question, as I understand your scenario, you can not delete a location and keep the authors. I am assuming that many authors are related to the same location. So, if you delete the location, what should happen with the references from all the authors to that location?

Comment: l.save() gives you a problem? I don't have this issue. I am actually following a tutorial which is why I did not use `failedOnError: true`. But, it seems you did answer my question that in this scenario I cannot delete a location even if I set its parent Author's location property to null before attempting the deletion.